# R^2 not appearing in stats.probplot (python)

Tags: python, plot, statistics, probability

Does anyone know if anything changed recently in stats.probplot? I am plotting a qq plot, and it works ok, but doesn't produce the R^2 statistic... Not sure why that would be?

```
x = stats.norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size=100)
stats.probplot(x, dist='norm', plot=pylab)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add rvalue=True as a parameter of stats.probplot

Comment: Thanks it works. Do you know if it was a recent update?